# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Tags: c#, .net

When I am executing my code on visual studio it is working good, but when i execute my exe file, it is throwing an exception.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
 at QuoteExtractor.frmQuoteExtractor.cmdProcess_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

My code

```
    private void cmdProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            foreach (string line in rtfMain.Lines)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (line.Trim() != "")
                    {
                        if ((line != "") && (line != " ") && (line.Substring(0, 3) != "***") && (line.Substring(0, 5) != "CUSIP"))
                        {
                            Quote q = new Quote();
                            q.Parse(line);
                            DisplayQuote(q);
                            QuoteList.Add(q);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Input:

```
   *** 9:30 AM ***    
   CUSIP          BOND NAME              SIZE       CURR FACE     TALK        COVER PX 
   004421GU1     ACE 2004-HE2 M2       10.000MM     1.103MM               dnt, 90 rsrv
   61744CTZ9     MSHEL 2005-3 M3       4.720MM      4.720MM               dnt
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory.  Post your input and you have a better chance of getting an answer that will help you.

Answer (score 16):

Read the error message.<sup>1</sup> One of

```
line.Substring(0, 3) != "***"
```

or

```
line.Substring(0, 5) != "CUSIP"
```

is bad because the length of `line` is less than three or five, respectively. Also, use [`String.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/baketfxw.aspx) for this purpose.

<sup>1</sup>: The error message is practically screaming at you:

> `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`: `Index` and `length` must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: **`length`** at `System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)` at `System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)`

It could not be any more clear that there is a problem with the *`length`* argument that you're passing to `String.Substring`. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx):

> #### Exceptions
>
> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`
>
> `startIndex` plus `length` indicates a position not within this instance.
>
> -or-
>
> `startIndex` or `length` is less than zero.

Your `startIndex` values aren't less than zero. Your `length` values aren't less than zero. That rules out the second possibility. The first possibility is that `startIndex` plus `length` indicates a position not within the string. Your `startIndex` values are zero, so `startIndex` plus `length` equals `length`. So the error message is telling you that `length` refers to a position not within the string. Thus, `length` *exceeds* the length of your string. It *can not* be anymore clear.

Comment: `!String.IsNullorEmpty(line.Trim()) && !line.StartsWith("***") && !line.StartsWith("CUSIP")`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know if your string actually contains enough characters for a substring, you should use [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/baketfxw.aspx) for your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The exception are saying you that on

```
line.Substring(0, 3) != "***"
```

or on

```
line.Substring(0, 5) != "CUSIP"
```

you are referring a string location that does not exist, probably because the `line` value length is less than expected.

An alternate piece of code could be...

```
private void cmdProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string line in rtfMain.Lines)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()) 
                        && !line.StartsWith("***") 
                        && !line.StartsWith("CUSIP"))
        {
            Quote q = new Quote();
            q.Parse(line);
            DisplayQuote(q);
            QuoteList.Add(q);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is not working, it is not showing any data except headers

Comment: I'm still having problem when i run my exe file after i changing the code, i don't know why? There is no problem when i execute my code in visual studio, I have to give exe file to the end user..

Comment: In which line of my suggested code are you experimenting the exception raise?

Comment: Its not giving any line in particular. QuoteExtractor.frmQuoteExtractor.cmdProcess_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Trace it to determine where your code is failing... Use `MessageBox.Show("Under if");` statements over your code to determine where your code is reaching.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with the attached code - VS doesn't catch the error if the "line" string is less than 57 chars. It doesn't react to the test code either - that code is from a test project I've made in another concurrent instance of VS where the debugger **does** catch the error. If I put the code in the main project in a try-catch it does get the error though.

I've seen it once before and suspect it's either a bug in Visual Studio (2008 Pro in this case - don't know if it affects later versions, just upgraded to VS 2013 and haven't seen it there yet) or caused by a corrupted project file.

```
        while (rf.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            line = rf.ReadLine().Trim();

            MessageBox.Show(line.Length.ToString());

            // test
            string x = "abc";
            string y = x.Substring(0, 20);
            // end test

            if (line.Substring(0, 57) == "<td align=\"right\" nowrap=\"nowrap\"><span       class=\"currency\">")
            {
                break;
            }

            // some more code 
        }
```